# How to transfer data from old database to new modified database in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, migration, django-3.0

I have old django project and new django project. I created **dump** file from database of old django. And also I made changes in tables and created new tables.

Now I want to load that dump file to my new django app. I am facing errors when I firstly migrate then restore data or  firstly restore then migrate..
When I  do migration first, it says  **tables already exist**.

When I do restore first , it says `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists`
I use `migrate --fake` **error goes** but **new tables are not created in database**.

I spent 3-4 days but could not succeed.

Please, help me if you can.

PS: my database is **postgresql**

Comment: is the new database containing new tables only or you added columns to the current tables as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* straightforward and will need some manual interventions and it depends on what do you want to do in the future

- If the tables that already exist in the database have a stable design and won't be changed or you can do the changes manually using SQL statements then set `managed = False` to the models' meta, this will make Django skip making migrations for those models
- If you want to keep the power of migration in the new project for all models then this will more complex

  1. Delete all your migrations
  2. You need to make your models equivalent to your database, you can set `managed=False` for  new models like `Users`
  3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`, this will create the structure of the initial database.
  4. Fake running the migrations `python manage.py migrate --fake`
  5. Dump the records of django_migrations table
  6. Create a new empty migration (with --empty) and add the SQL statements of the `django_migrations` table to it using `migrations.RunSQL()`
  7. now fake again so you skip that new migration.
  8. Now you are ready to use migrations as usual.

When installing new database, you will just need to run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I have used managed=False 

and followed steps below

1) restore dump file
2) delete all previous migrations from DB

3) delete all previous migrations from files

4) makemigrations

5) migrate

6) migrate --fake

worked for me.